# Syntax for using collate nocase in a SQLite replace function

Tags: sqlite, collate

I have an existing database where they created theiw own unicode collation sequence.  I'm trying to use the following code and get a "no such collation sequence" exception.  Can anybdy hlep with the the syntax to use "collate nocase" with this code?

update Songs set
  SongPath = replace (SongPath, 'Owner.Funkytown', 'Jim');

Answer (score 0):

Dump database (via shell), edit output SQL (find and change column definitions, set COLLATION NOCASE). Recreate database.